# path name and arguments of running processes using java code

Tags: java, process

I want to get the path name and arguments of running processes using java code. Is there any solution?

Comment: Under which operating system?

Answer (score 3):

For instance, on Windows, one possibility is to encapsulate the [system call to `TASKLIST.EXE`](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0593.html)

Extract from the code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe /fo csv /nh");
      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
          if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
              // keep only the process name
              line = line.substring(1);
              processes.add(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(""")));
          }

      }
```

You should use `tasklist /V` though, since it comes with the parameters of the processes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SIGAR](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) framework, which gives you native support for Linux, FreeBSD, Windows, Solaris, AIX, HP-UX and Mac OSX